Missing Cloudflare DB binding (D1)
I am having trouble with NuxtHub with D1 database.
in wrangler.toml, I've already have d1 database binding specified (i've removed the value from the code below on purpose)
I can see the D1 database name and the variable name appear in the project Functions -> D1 database bindings.
when the app run, it throws "Missing Cloudflare DB binding (D1)".
Please help.

in wrangler.toml, the binding must be "DB"
binding = "DB"

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
